# one to many and many to one relation in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Hi,
I am quite new to hibernate.I have one class Customer which has one to many relation with Order class and Oder class is having one to many relation with Item class and many to One with Customer.and Item Class is having one to many relation with Product class.
my hbm.xml look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.xyz.hibernet.dto.Customer" table="CUSTOMER" abstract="true">
        <id name="cid"  type="java.lang.Integer" column="CUST_ID" >
        <generator class="native"/>
         </id>
        <property name="cname" column="CUST_NAME"/>
        <list name="orderList" cascade="all">
           <key column="CUST_ID"/>
           <index column="idx"/>
            <one-to-many class="com.activenet.hibernet.dto.Order"/>
         </list>
    </class>



    <class name="com.xyz.hibernet.dto.Order" table="ORDER">
        <id name="oid" type="java.lang.Integer" column="O_ID" >
             <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="odate" column="ORDER_DATE"/>
        <property name="amt" column="AMOUNT"/>
        <set name="itemSet" inverse="true" cascade="all">
            <key column="O_ID"/>
            <one-to-many class="com.activenet.hibernet.dto.Item"/>
        </set>
        <many-to-one name="oCustomer" class="com.activenet.hibernet.dto.Customer" column="CUST_ID"/>
    </class>

    <class  name="com.xyz.hibernet.dto.Item" table="ITEM">

        <id name="iid" type="java.lang.Integer" column="ITEM_ID" >
             <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="quantity" column="ORDER_QTY"/>
        <many-to-one name="product" class="com.activenet.hibernet.dto.Product" column="PRODUCT_ID"/>
    </class>
    <class  name="com.xyz.hibernet.dto.Product" table="PRODUCT">

        <id name="pid" type="java.lang.Integer" >
            <column name="PROD_ID" />
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="pname" column="PROD_NAME"/>
        <property name="price" column="PROD_PRICE"/>
        <property name="descr" column="PROD_DESC"/>

    </class>

<!--    <query name="findAllCustomers">
    <![CDATA[from com.xyz.hibernet.dto.Customer c where c.name=:name]]>
    </query>-->

</hibernate-mapping>
```

And

Customer Class look like below

```
 import java.util.List;

 public class Customer {

private int cid;
private String cname;
private List orderList;

public Customer()
{
    super();
}
public Customer(int cid,String cname, List orderList)
{
    super();
    this.cid=cid;
    this.cname=cname;
    this.orderList=orderList;
}
--setter and getter 
 }
```

**Product.java**

```
   public class Product {

private int pid;
private String pname;
private double price;
private String descr;

public Product() {
    super();
}

public Product(int pid,String pname,double price,String descr) {
    super();
    this.pid=pid;
    this.pname=pname;
    this.price=price;
    this.descr=descr;
}

Setter and getter methods----here   
}
```

**Order.java**

```
  public class Order {

private int oid;
private Date odate;
private double amt;
private Set itemSet;
private Customer oCustomer;

    public Order()
{
    super();
}
   public Order(int oid,Date odate,double amt, Set itemSet)
   {
 super();
 this.oid=oid;
 this.odate=odate;
 this.itemSet=itemSet;
 this.amt=amt;
   }
 -- setter and getter
   }
```

**Item.java**

```
  public class Item {

private int iid;
private Product product;
private int quantity;
public Item ()
{
    super();
}

public Item (int iid,Product product,int quantity)
{
    super();
    this.iid=iid;
    this.product=product;
    this.quantity=quantity;
}
```

}

My Test Class look like below

```
    public class TestCustomer {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    SessionFactory oSessionFac=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session oSession=oSessionFac.openSession();
    Transaction oTransaction=oSession.beginTransaction();

    //-------------------------->New product Insertion<-------------------------------

    Product product1=new Product(0,"Master in EJB",350.00,"Good Luck");
    Product product2=new Product(0,"Master in STRUTS",250.00,"Good Luck");
    Product product3=new Product(0,"Master in WEBSERVICE",150.00,"Good Luck");
    Product product4=new Product(0,"Master in JSF",450.00,"Good Luck");
    Product product5=new Product(0,"Master in SPRING",550.00,"Good Luck");
    oSession.save(product1);
    oSession.save(product2);
    oSession.save(product3);
    oSession.save(product4);
    oSession.save(product5);
    oTransaction.commit();
    System.out.println("::::::::::::product is inserted::::::::::::::");
    //<----------------------Place One Order into new Customer------------------------>

    Product prod1=(Product)oSession.load(Product.class, 1);

    Product prod2=(Product)oSession.load(Product.class, 2);

    Product prod3=(Product)oSession.load(Product.class, 3);

    Item oItem1 =new Item(0,prod1,1);

    Item oItem2 =new Item(0,prod2,1);

    Item oItem3 =new Item(0,prod3,1);

    Item oItem4 =new Item(0,prod1,2);
    Set<Item> set=new HashSet<Item>();
    set.add(oItem1);set.add(oItem2);set.add(oItem3);set.add(oItem4);

    Order oOrder=new Order(0,Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),1200.00,set);

    List<Order> list=new ArrayList<Order>();
    list.add(oOrder);
    oSession.persist(oOrder);
    Customer customer1=new Customer(0,"ABC",list);
    //oOrder=new Order(0,Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),1200.00,set,customer1);
    oSession.saveOrUpdate(customer1);

    oTransaction.commit();
    oSession.flush();
    }
```

}

**I have used org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect dialect**

While trying to excute the code it is saying
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER (ORDER_DATE, AMOUNT, CUST_ID) values ('2012-03-07 11:58:55', 1200.0, null)' at line 1**

I tried a lot but could not fix it. Please any one help me where is the problem

Comment: ORDER is a reserved word in mysql no? `table="´ORDER´"` might help

Comment: Yah it is working if I chage table="ORDER" to some other name

Answer (score 0):

Because `Customer` (i.e `oCustomer`) instance in the  `Order` (i.e `oOrder`)  is not set (i.e  NULL) , hibernate will insert NULL for the column `ORDER.CUST_ID` . It definitely will throw out errors as this column has the FK constraint to the customer which cannot accept NULL.

First , let the Order has the responsibility to  handle the relationship between Customer and Order by setting the `inverse` attribute of `<set>` inside the Customer to true.

(P.S `inverse` attribute is very difficult to understand for the beginner IMO , but you can easily search out many resources about this attribute . Normally , in `<one-to-many>` relationship , we set it to `true` in the  collection tag (i.e. `<set>` , `<list>`))

Then set customer1 to be the customer of oOrder before saving, likes this:

```
 Customer customer1=new Customer();
 customer1.setCid(0);
 customer1.setCname("ABC");

 Order oOrder=new Order();
 oOrder.setOid(0);
 oOrder.setOdate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
 oOrder.setAmt(1200.00);
 oOrder.setItemSet(itemSet);
 oOrder.setOcustomer(customer1);

 oSession.save(customer1); 
 oSession.save(oOrder);
```

Comment: if you look in the question you will see that the inverse attribute is already set to true. You are right about the Order.Customer not set to the customer though